# My for loop won't display my object, but no errors show up

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, flash-cs3

For some reason my for loop isn't working, the enemies won't spawn and nothing appears in the Output when I used `trace`.   However, there also is no error, so I'm wondering what the issue is.

Here is my code:

```
var playerX = 0;
var playerY = 0;

var mapWidth = 5000;
var mapHeight = 5000;

//enemy
var myEnemies:Array = new Array();
var enemySprite:Sprite;
var Enemy:enemy;
var enemyCount:int = 0;

//event listeners

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spawnEnemies);

//spawn enemies
function spawnEnemies(spawn:Event) {
    if (enemyCount < 20) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myEnemies.length; i++) {
            enemySprite = new Sprite();
            this.addChild(enemySprite);
            Enemy = new enemy();
            Enemy.x = (Math.random() * this.width);
            Enemy.y = (Math.random() * this.height);
            enemySprite.addChild(Enemy);

            enemyCount++;
            myEnemies[enemyCount] = enemySprite;
            trace(myEnemies.length);
        }
         stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveEnemy);
    }
}

//move the enemies
function moveEnemy(enemyMovement:Event){
    for (var k = 0; k < myEnemies.length; k++) {
        trace("move enemy");
        if (myEnemies[k].y > playerY) {
            myEnemies[k].y -= 1;
            myEnemies[k].rotation = 0;
        }
        else if (myEnemies[k].x < playerX) {
           myEnemies[k].x += 1;
           myEnemies[k].rotation = 90;
        } 
        else if (myEnemies[k].y < playerY) {
           myEnemies[k].y += 1;
           myEnemies[k].rotation = 180;
        }
        else {
           myEnemies[k].x -= 1;
           myEnemies[k].rotation = 270;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure that they're not simply just spawning on coordinates that aren't visible?

Comment: Initially nothing in myEnemies array so loop conditions (k < myEnemies.length) is false  so it is not working.

Comment: How would I fix that so that there is something in the myEnemies array loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did not work with AS3 for a long time, but... Why do you expect new enemies to be created if myEnemies length is 0?
Also, you created two different ENTER_FRAME functions and there is no need to do that. Create only one function and call it for exmaple update:

```
private function update(e:event)
{

}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
```

You should not create new sprites using for loop inside ENTER_FRAME function, because this function runs 30 or more times in a second.
Create for loop inside "init" or "create" function, unless you want to update code on each frame.

Add 10 enemies:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Enemy = new enemy();
        Enemy.x = (Math.random() * this.width);
        Enemy.y = (Math.random() * this.height);
        this.addChild(Enemy);
        // add it to array
        myEnemies.push(Enemy);
    }
```

You cannot use myEnemies to create new Enemy sprite because it's empty, so you create 0 enemies. If you want to create 10 enemies use this code, or simple change number 10 to any number you want.

Comment: @jelly I have updated my answer, it shows how to actually add some enemies on the stage.